# MySQL join empty rows

Tags: mysql, select, join, where-clause

I'm trying to construct a simple query in for getting users with particular meta fields (this is in Wordpress, but doesn't matter cause it's raw sql)

A simple query i did looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM wp_sb_users u
 LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_sb_usermeta m ON (u.ID=m.user_id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_sb_usermeta mm ON (u.ID=mm.user_id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_sb_usermeta mmm ON (u.ID=mmm.user_id)
WHERE
 m.meta_key = "autostatus" AND
 mm.meta_key = "first_name" AND
 mmm.meta_key = "last_name"
```

though i have only one small trouble -- if `mmm.meta_key = "last_name"` doesn't exist at all, the row isn't returned.. i tried `mmm.meta_key <=> "last_name"` but then it takes any other meta_key (like "user_email") and puts there in row, which then results in having a user with first name Alex and last name my@email.com

I also tried (mmm.meta_key = "last_name" OR mmm.meta_key IS NULL), but it doesn't work too

Help me figure it out please

PS
the tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_sb_users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_login` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_pass` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_nicename` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_url` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_activation_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `display_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
  KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=30 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_sb_usermeta` (
  `umeta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`umeta_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=792 ;
```

Comment: please explain what you are trying to accomplish here, and maybe include the structure of the above tables? this will help us help you better.

Comment: Please tell us what you get from this query and what would you expect to receive

Comment: sorry, added table structure.. so what i am trying to do is get users with their particular meta fields defined in other table, EVEN if no such meta field exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_sb_users u
 LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_sb_usermeta m ON (u.ID=m.user_id and m.meta_key = "autostatus")
 LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_sb_usermeta mm ON (u.ID=mm.user_id and mm.meta_key = "first_name")
 LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_sb_usermeta mmm ON (u.ID=mmm.user_id and mmm.meta_key = "last_name")
```

Comment: you know what, i just tried that and it worked! seems like WHERE is kinda strict for selects, and putting conditions in ON is more loosy

Comment: Your meta_key is part of your join criteria.  If you do your original query without your WHERE clause, you'll realise what the dataset you were filtering looked like.

Comment: And just a tip for when you do queries with no WHERE condition, end your query with something like `LIMIT 100` so you don't try to fetch a million records, which can easily happen when outer joining over multiple tables